# Hot to use jquery promise with file Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

I am trying to upload an image using a fine Uploader plug-in and i want to send some form data along with the image but the form data is not available to me at the time of initializing the plugin(according to the requirements of the plugin it should be given at the time of initialization). Is it possible to use jquery Promise for this purpose if yes How?

```
/*--  Create Rack Image Uploads  --*/

$('.rack-create-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#createRackImageUpload').fineUploader({
        template: 'qq-template-manual-trigger',
        multiple: false,
        autoUpload: false,
        request: {
            endpoint: 'upload_shop_rack',
            // customHeaders:{data:$('#createRack').serialize()},
            params:{data:{ 
                            name:''//,I want promimse Here
                            value:'Human Value'
            } 
        },
        session: {
            endpoint: 'get_rack_image',
            refreshOnRequest: true,
        },
        validation: {
            allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'],
            sizeLimit: 5242880,
            itemLimit: 1

        },
        messages: {
            tooManyItemsError: 'You can only add 1 image'
        },
        deleteFile: {
            enabled: true,
            forceConfirm: true,
            endpoint: 'delete_shop_rack'
        }
    });
    $('.trigger-upload').click(function (e) {
        Var createRackForM=$('#cresteRack').serialize();
        $('#createRackImageUpload').fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles');
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry don't know how to add code

Comment: Would this help you? http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#form

Comment: I've tried going throught the documentation but it does'nt have any feature to add dynamic data after initialization

Comment: Did you click the link? It talks about how it can include form data which it seems you're trying to do.

Comment: yes but that's in case you use a simple html form and Submit Button which is not my case.

Comment: alright. I guess the other option would be to delay initialization of fineUploader until after you have the data you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include any parameters with any upload request at any time using Fine Uploader's [`setParams` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#setParams). For example:

```
callbacks: {
   onUpload: function(id) {
      this.setParams(id, {someData: 'someValue'})
   }
}
```

Comment: its not working either setParams is for get request I am trying to upload and image using the Fine-Uploader UI and want some form data to be  sent along for the ride

Comment: That will send form data, assuming the request is multipart encoded (which it is by default).

Comment: thanks for the help made a few changes with your code and it works fine